# -vmargs Goes Missing During Tycho Build

Tags: eclipse-rcp, tycho

I've a problem with my Tycho build. I've got a standard RCP product that starts the application. And a Tycho configuration like this:

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>materialize-products</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>archive-products</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>archive-products</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <products>
                    <product>
                        <id>${project.artifactId}</id>
                        <attachId>${project.artifactId}</attachId>
                        <archiveFileName>${archiveName}</archiveFileName>
                    </product>
                </products>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This is the entire configuration, and it's probably the most minimalistic one possible.

Which makes what happens during the Tycho build even weirder. The product file defines the following program arguments:

```
-clean 
-persistState false
-vmargs --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

After the build the `-vmargs` is missing, so the INI file looks like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-clean
-persistState
false
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

This means the application does not work with this file, because `--add-modules` somehow needs `-vmargs` to work.

I have no idea where to even start debugging this problem. Why does Tycho remove the `-vmargs` argument and how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: An xxx.product file has separate sections for program and VM arguments and doesn't normally contain '-vmargs'

Comment: @greg-449 Ah, of course! That was easier (and stupider on my part) than expected.